# Is there a way to get the list of scenarios that are to be run in the @BeforeClass annotation in cucumber JVM

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

I have got a requirement to get the list of all the scenarios that are to be executed based on the tag I provided in cucumber Test runner. However I have to get this list before tests start execution.

I know there is a tag called "@BeforeClass" but I am not sure if I can use to get the list of all the scenarios that are going to be run. For example something like this

```
 @BeforeClass
public void intialize(Scenario[] scenario) throws Exception { }
```

Below is the code for me test runner class

```
    package com.automation.cucumber;

import com.automation.Utils;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;
import io.cucumber.testng.*;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

import java.io.File;

@CucumberOptions(features = "features/amazon"
        ,glue="com.automation.cucumber"
        ,tags = "@tt"
        ,dryRun = true
        , plugin = {"json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json"})

public class CucumberTestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    static String resultFolder;
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void intialize() throws Exception {
        resultFolder =  Utils.createTestReportFolder();
        if(resultFolder==null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to create a result folder");
        }

        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to implement [EventListener](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.cucumber/cucumber-core/4.7.2/cucumber/api/event/EventListener.html) class to get that information and do `dryRun = true` in your `Runner` class in `@CucumberOptions`

Quoting from a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535160/how-can-gets-all-tags-and-cucumber-scenarios-without-run-tests) that can help you achieve what you need

```
public class DryRunPlugin implements EventListener {

    @Override
    public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestCaseStarted.class, this::handleCaseStarted);
    }

    private void handleCaseStarted(TestCaseStarted event) {
        System.out.println(event.getTestCase().getUri());
        System.out.println(event.getTestCase().getName());
        System.out.println(event.getTestCase().getScenarioDesignation());
        event.getTestCase().getTags().stream().forEach(t -> 
        System.out.println(t.getName()));
    }

}
```

Comment: is there a way to get read the datatable attached to the step. I am using cucumber version 5.5 ? I tried using "Object dataTable = p.getStep().getArgument();"  but i am not able to iterate over the cells to read and print the values